# Covert one character into one column

Tags: r, dataframe, file, split, character

I have text files I want to convert one character into one column. I tried with `strplit`  but didn't get desired output.

```
test1.txt
ATTGCATGTACGTATCGTTGAC

test2.txt
ACCCGCGGGGNNCGTATCGAAGAC
```

expected output

```
test1.txt

V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 ...
A   T T  G   C

test2.txt
V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 ...
A  C  C   C  G
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string <- readLines('test1.txt')
as.data.frame(t(strsplit(string, '')[[1]]))

  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18 V19 V20 V21 V22
1  A  T  T  G  C  A  T  G  T   A   C   G   T   A   T   C   G   T   T   G   A   C
```

Answer (score 0):

`strsplit` option and changing the columnames to V1 etc like this:

```r
test1.txt <- c("ATTGCATGTACGTATCGTTGAC")
output <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(test1.txt, "")))
names(output) <- paste0("V", 1:length(output))
output
#>   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18 V19 V20 V21
#> 1  A  T  T  G  C  A  T  G  T   A   C   G   T   A   T   C   G   T   T   G   A
#>   V22
#> 1   C
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>